# Android - How to get ListView text?

Tags: java, android

I'm a complete newbie to Android, and this may actually be more of a Java question...

I'm trying to set up an if statement based on the item clicked in a ListView. In my onItemClick method I have the following:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

if(((TextView) view).getText() == "Page 1"){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Page 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The string populating my ListView has "Page 1"; I see the first Toast saying "Page 1", but I never get the "Page 1 clicked" Toast, so obviously something about my if statement is wonky. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing Strings in Java, you should use `equals()`:

```
if (((TextView) view).getText().equals("Page 1")) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Coming from a .Net background, I'm gonna need to brush up on Java syntax obviously...