# Why strings are not equal

Tags: android

In my android app, I have a Play button. but after I clicked the button, nothing happend. Seems when comparing the text on the button, they are not equal. if I use indexOf(PLAY), it works. Cannot figure out why it behaves like this. I defined my string values in res/values/strings.xml  as

```
    <string name="play">Play</string>

    private final static String PLAY = "Play";        

    //some code in between    

    Button playButton = new Button(this);
    playButton.setText(R.string.play);
    playButton.setTextSize(BUTTON_FONT_SIZE);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Button b = (Button) v;
           if (b.getText().equals(PLAY)) {    //stuck here.                                    
                 startPlay();
            } else {

                stopPlay();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: add some logs and see if b.getText() is not returning null

Comment: on a side note, depending on your problem space it can be considered good practice to convert both strings to either lower or uppercase before comparing them. This can save time during later debugging

Comment: I do have debug output and visually they are the same. but when I try to use "string size=" + R.string.play.length, it gives error: int cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use an intermediate variable? Like : `String buttonText = b.getText().toString();` `if(buttonText.equals(PLAY)....?`

Comment: @jbihan You got it. Thanks a bunch. I thought toString() is not needed.

Comment: You're welcome, let me add it as an answer then ;)

Comment: @jbihan why toString() is needed? see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199320/android-how-to-get-listview-text?rq=1 . It works without toString(), but mine does not work. I know button.getText() returns CharSequence.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, it was just a guess. I saw links like the one you gave me, I thought it didn't understand why it didn't work so I tried to find an alternative solution. But I agree with you, it's strange... I'll try to find out why! (and if you find out, let me know!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an intermediate variable, like this

```
String buttonText = b.getText().toString(); 
if (buttonText.equals(PLAY)) { 
    .....
```

Or just

```
if (b.getText().toString().equals(PLAY)) {
```